# how can i use output from sprintf as the filename for fopen?

Tags: c, file-io

I am working on a log parsing program that retrieves the file to open by combining an environment variable and a preset string in order to provide the full path to the file, but i am having trouble getting fopen to take out the output from sprintf which i am using to combine the environment variable and the preset string,so i was wondering if anyone could offer advice on what i should do to get this to work properly? thanks! (i have just begun teaching myself C over the last few weeks, so im open to any tips no matter how obvious they should be to me)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
void main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  FILE *fd; // File pointer
  char *name;
  char *filename[];
  name = getenv("MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME");
  sprintf(filename,"/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-%s.txt",name);
  char buff[1024];
  if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) // open file
  {
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // make sure start from 0

    while(!feof(fd))
    {
      memset(buff, 0x00, 1024); // clean buffer
      fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff); // read file *prefer using fscanf
    }
    printf("Last Line :: %s\n", buff);
  }
  else
  printf( "fail" );
}
```

here is the error i get while compiling using gcc

```
lastline.c: In function ‘main’:
lastline.c:9: error: array size missing in ‘filename’
lastline.c:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdio.h:341: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type   ‘char **’
lastline.c:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdio.h:249: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of   type ‘char **’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *filename[];
```

declares an array of pointers to `char` of unknown size. You need an array of `char` to `sprintf` to, of sufficient known length. Declare

```
char filename[1000];  // assuming 1000 is large enough
```

or

```
char *filename;
```

as a pointer to `char` and `malloc` sufficient memory after you have gotten the name,

```
filename = malloc(sizeof "/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-.txt" - 1 + strlen(name) + 1);
if (!filename) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

to avoid unpleasant surprises if `name` turns out longer than expected.

Comment: Many people would prefer sizeof()-1 for string constants over strlen(), even though strlen() often is a compiler built in function which will be optimized out.

Comment: Good point, since we also want space for the 0-terminator, `sizeof` even gets rid of the `+1`.

Comment: About "getting rid of -1": sizeof()-1 + strlen() + 1 makes the intention clear. Using only sizeof()+strlen() one has to look closer to see that both strlen and sizeof are used, and enough space for the \0 was allocated.